# MIT Scheme - Merge Sort + Timing Execution

Tags: scheme, runtime, mergesort, timing, mit-scheme

I've implemented my own merge sort in MIT Scheme. I want to test it against the builtin `merge-sort` and compare times; however, I don't know how to get the run time of both. Also how do you increase the stack size/recursion depth as i'm testing up to 1 million elements.

Comment: FYI bottom-up mergesort does not require recursion and can be naturally implemented with a loop.

Comment: Thanks! I might try that to reduce overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of timing procedures in MIT Scheme, check the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Machine-Time.html). In particular, try this one:

```
(with-timings
 (lambda ()
   (merge-sort '(1 2 3 4 5) >))
 (lambda (run-time gc-time real-time)
   (write (internal-time/ticks->seconds run-time))
   (write-char #\space)
   (write (internal-time/ticks->seconds gc-time))
   (write-char #\space)
   (write (internal-time/ticks->seconds real-time))
   (newline)))
```

The built-in `sort` shouldn't have a problem with one million elements, *if* your own implementation is a good one, it shouldn't have problems producing a result with that data size.

Comment: Thank you friend :)